# What's the difference between UIImage's tint vs UIImageView's tint, and which one should I use?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have this code:

```
    var itemIconImage = UIImage(cgImage: item.image)
    if item.shouldOverlay {
      itemIconImage = itemIconImage.withTintColor(.black, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
    }
    itemIcon = UIImageView(image: itemIconImage)
```

I realized that there are 2 tint colors:

1. UIImage's withTintColor API, as shown here
2. UIImageView's tint color (the above code would be `itemIcon.tintColor = .black`)

I am wondering what's the difference between these 2? And which one should I use?

Comment: Are you asking because both give the same end result or because the end result is different between the two?

Comment: They are different. Though I was more curious in the reasons behind, rather than just try both out and pick the working solution and call it a day.

Comment: The curiosity is a good thing. I wanted to know what results you saw before trying to answer. Of course the results do depend on the rendering mode of the original image.

Comment: the result is that the image's tint color works, but image view's tint color doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageView tintColor` applies the tint to whatever image happens to be in the image view. And it will only have an effect if the image's rendering mode allows it to take any effect. You need a tintable symbol image for this approach to work.

`UIImage withTintColor` creates a new image with the given tint and rendering mode. The results depend on the original image type. The documentation states:

> For bitmap images, this method draws the background tint color followed by the image contents using the CGBlendMode.destinationIn mode. For symbol images, this method returns an image that always uses the specified tint color.

The [Providing images for different appearances](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/providing_images_for_different_appearances) page in the documentation covers how to create tintable symbol images.

If you start with such an image, the results of using `UIImageView tintColor` and `UIImage withTintColor` will give the same results. But other types of images with different rendering modes will give different results.

If you have a tintable symbol image that will only be used in a single image view then it's a tiny bit easier to set the image view's `tintColor` property.

If you want to tint an image for use outside of an image view or if the image isn't a tintable symbol image, then use `withTintColor` on the image.